# Playframewok [Java]: Upgrading from 2.3.2 to 2.4.11 causes 'ConfigException' exception

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I followed all the below link for upgrading my Play application:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24

I updated my Java to `1.8`, and my activator version is `1.2.2`.

I am getting this below error after updating my Play project from version 2.3.3 to 2.4.11:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:535)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:535)
at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:157)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$.com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load(SbtWeb.scala:549)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$globalSettings$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:143)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$globalSettings$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:143)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Function1.scala:55)
at sbt.Project$.setProject(Project.scala:319)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:484)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

> my project/plugins.sbt file is

```
    logLevel := Level.Warn

    resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.11")

    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")

    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")

    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
```

my build.sbt file is

```
sbtPlugin := true

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-feature")

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaCore,
  javaJdbc,
  evolutions,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.11-1",
  "org.webjars" % "underscorejs" % "1.6.0-3",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "1.11.1",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.1-1" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
  "org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.2.16-2" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
  "org.webjars" % "ng-table" % "0.3.3" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.168",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-core" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-orm" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-tx" % "3.2.1.RELEASE"
)
```

Comment: what's the output to java and javac -version?, also JAVA_HOME env variable

Comment: the output of java and javac -version is-> java version "1.8.0_171" and JAVA_HOME env variable is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: Please, edit your question and attach /project/build.properties file